# Why are my requests from HTTPS domain to HTTP localhost failing CORS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cors, azure-functions

I have a rest service (implemented as an Azure Function), running on HTTPS, on domain A.

I have a web site, running on HTTPS on domain B.

I have specified wildcard * for cors.

Using jQuery on the web site I send Ajax requests to the rest service. This works, I can see my `GET` request preflighted by an `OPTIONS`.

[image]

When I am developing my rest service I would like to host the service locally, running on HTTP, on the localhost domain. This doesnt seem to work.

I have to enable mixed content, but then it doesnt seem like the browser (Firefox) sends or preflights my request - the network traffic is empty. It looks like my request is failing the CORS request.

This appears in the Firefox console.

```
16:42:56.550 Loading mixed (insecure) active content "http://locahost:7071/api/test/get?message=get+hello+world!" on a secure page[Learn More] ajax.ts:153:23
16:42:56.558 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://locahost:7071/api/test/get?message=get+hello+world!. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I am able to avoid the mixed content errors by setting my local url as `//locahost`, however this still fails CORS.

Does this happen because I am trying to do CORS from HTTPS domain to HTTP localhost?

Comment: If you are hard coding the `http://` into your url for the ajax, try changing it to just `//`.  If you perform an ajax request starting with `//` it will use whatever protocol the page used when it first loaded.  This way you can avoid doing a different protocol than what the page is.

Comment: Do you have the property `"CORS": "*"` inside of your `local.settings.json` file?

Comment: @MarkC. Yes, I've also tried supplying `--cors *` as an application argument.

Comment: @Taplar, nice idea, however similiar result. The browser preflights a request to `https://`, which my service doesnt respond to, so CORS still fails.

Comment: it may still fail the CORS, but that should fix your mixed active content error.

Comment: @Taplar, I hadnt noticed, indeed it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this page shows details reason: Mixed content is blocked as default.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

you have to enable local https as well if you did not setup allowed domain list, not only Firefox, but also Chrome & IE block those request that is from https to http. 
BTW, you cannot use self-assigned certificates in local host, it will be blocked as well with another error.

Comment: Whilst that covers the mixed content and makes sense, it doesnt mention anything about CORS which I believe to be the real issue. E.g. I can enable mixed content in my browser and still receive the same error.

Comment: To expand, I'm not sure if your answer is about mixed content only, or mixed content and CORS?

Comment: Actually both of them. mixed-content error only happens in cors requests, specifically https to http, it's multiple domains.  I had totally same usage as yours last year. white list does not work somewhere as well, no matter how you setup http, my finally solution was to switch local host to https, then assign it a good certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Done a bit of digging, as far as I can tell there are a few things coming into play here.

## CORS

HTTPS domain to HTTP localhost rightly causes CORS validation. I believe I have CORS correctly configured for my service.

However I believe the browsers have particular behaviours when dealing with localhost, which are causing my issue.

## Tests

I am using [Rest test test](https://resttesttest.com/) on HTTPS and a locally hosted [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) on HTTP to run tests outside of my rest service (Azure Functions).

I am comparing those tests to the HTTPS hosted version of JSON Server at [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

I am doing two types of test, [simple and preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios) as they elicit different behaviours. Preflighted has a custom header, which results in an `OPTIONS` request before the `GET`.

[image: Base tests]

## Browser Behaviours on Localhost with Protection Disabled

*TL/DR: Simple and preflighted requests do not work on Firefox or Chrome.*

### Firefox

To allow mixed content (HTTP in HTTPS) protection must be disabled, otherwise nothing happens and `Blocked loading mixed active content` errors are shown in the console.

[image: Firefox disable protection]

However even with protection disabled Firefox will continue to block simple and preflighted requests. For the preflighted requests Firefox will not issue any request what so ever. Warnings regarding mixed content and CORS are shown in the console.

[image: Firefox tested on localhost]

### Chrome

Like Firefox protection must be disabled to allow mixed content.

[image: Chrome protection]

Also like Firefox, Chrome will not successfully perform any request, however it will issue the preflight `OPTIONS`.

[image: Chrome localhost]

## Browser Behaviours on 127.0.0.1 with Protection Enabled

*TL/DR: In Chrome simple and preflighted requests work. For Firefox only simple requests work.*

It looks like there has been some work at [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=903966) and [Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/130ee686fa00b617bfc001ceb3bb49782da2cb4e) so http://127.0.0.1/ isn't treated as mixed content. Looks like the crowd at [WebKit/Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171934) are still thinking about it.

[The MDN docs have this note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).

> Since Firefox 55, the loading of mixed content is allowed on
>   http://127.0.0.1/ (see bug 903966). Chrome allows mixed content on
>   http://127.0.0.1/ and http://localhost/. Safari does not allow any
>   mixed content.

Based on the tests above I'm not sure that localhost on Chrome is true (at least anymore).

### Firefox

With protection enabled, Firefox works for simple requests. Preflighted requests still fail but only show CORS warnings (this might be a bug in Firefox, I'm not sure).

[image: Firefox on 127]

### Chrome

With protection enabled, simple and preflighted requests work.

[image: Chrome on 127]

## Azure Function

Coming back to my rest service implemented as Azure Functions. I thought I could just test my service over 127.0.0.1 using Chrome.

Unfortunealty, this won't work either.

Azure Functions are [hardcoded](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/174) to [localhost](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/91481cb48afcfda415ad5e4a350d203de5ece421/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/FunctionsLocalServer.cs#L45) and don't seem to respond to 127.0.0.1. E.g. I can't even browse to my API on 127.0.0.1 let alone make a web service call.

An alternative approach is required, I went with trying to setup up Azure Functions for HTTPS. [How to run Azure Function locally within Visual Studio on HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269657/how-to-run-azure-function-locally-within-visual-studio-on-https)

Comment: Clients will always decline the solution: enable mixed content manually by terminate users. the setting will be lost once browser refreshed cache. and clients manager don't want their users to set it manually and don't want them learn more to handle technical issues. actually before I switch to https, i want them temporally use that option, but they prefer to wait for perfect solution.

Comment: @Dongdong, this is just for testing during development, won't be deployed to users.

Comment: Sure. and this setting is easier in chrome, but hard for IE's family and Safari.