# How to run Azure Function locally within Visual Studio on HTTPS?

Tags: c#, https, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have a C# library Azure Function (v1 .Net Framework 4.6.1) developed in Visual Studio.

I want to run this locally within Visual Studio on HTTPS. How can I achieve this?

I have set my application arguments as follows:

```
host start --port 7112 --pause-on-error --useHttps --cors *
```

Adding `--usehttps` results in the application not starting correctly.

When the application starts it asks if I want to install a certificate, I click yes.

Then console window shows this and the application doesnt seem to load correctly - the final message just keeps repeating.

```
Listening on https://localhost:7112/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
[10/07/2018 15:52:58] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Application.Server\bin\Debug\net461\host.json'
[10/07/2018 15:52:58] Host configuration file read:
[10/07/2018 15:52:58] {}
The host is taking longer than expected to start.
```

(Aside; I am trying to do this because I think it might help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269439/why-are-my-ajax-requests-not-being-preflighted)).

Answer (score 5):

Please try creating a test cert using following commands in powershell

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject localhost -DnsName localhost -FriendlyName "Functions Development" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath certificate.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String <password> -Force -AsPlainText)
```

and here is the command to start functions host

```
func host start --port 7112 --useHttps --cors * --cert certificate.pfx --password <password>
```

Comment: I've had mixed success with this. I manage to get this working in one Azure Function project, but then it stopped working - I thought because I messed around with my certificates. I created a new project on a different machine, but these steps havn't worked on the second machine in a new project - I get "The host is taking longer than expected to start". Is there something else I should look at? Note; I'm running Visual Studio so I'm adding `host start...` into the application arguments.

Comment: I get the same problem if I run the project from the CLI.

Comment: Can you please open an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues with detailed repro steps and including the versions for VS 2017, Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools version , CLI and OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some time, I have found a workaround using ngrok.

[Piotr Stapp describes the process](https://stapp.space/how-to-test-azure-function-on-localhost-from-the-internet/).

> Run .`\ngrok authtoken aaa` to
>   generate a config file. Its location will be printed as output...replace content with following:
>
> ```
> tunnels:  
>   azurefunction:
>     proto: http
>     addr: 7071
>     host_header: localhost
> ```
>
> Run your Azure function on localhost from Visual Studio with F5 and in
>   PowerShell (or cmd) type:
>
> `.\ngrok.exe start azurefunction`